# iOS: Expected label height given width

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

```
sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:
```

has been deprecated in iOS7. I'm not sure how to include line breaks when using `sizeWithAttributes`.

Does anyone know of a good workaround? I'm trying to determine the expected height of an nsstring with given font and line break mode and width.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html

sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:

Returns the size of the string if it were to be rendered with the specified font and line attributes on a single line. (Deprecated in iOS 7.0. Use boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:.)